# Change checkout node of the Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have a possibility to set/change the default checkout node (currently: master) of the Jenkins shared library. This is because we are using Jenkins with many different teams and I would like to prevent any job executions on the master node.

```
@Library('my-shared-library') _ // <- it is about this step here
....

node("some_node_label") {
  ...
}
```

Even if the pipeline is using another node for the execution the checkout always happens on the master node.

I tried to move the @Library annotation within the node close but this also doesn't help me:

```
node("some_node_label") {
  @Library('my-shared-library') _ 
  ...
}
```

The job is always trying to start on the master node. Why?

[image]

It is possible to change the default behavior?

Comment: As of right now, all pipeline Groovy code is compiled and executed on the Jenkins master. This checkout behavior may be an optimization or just default behavior since it keeps the libraries close to where the pipeline code is used.

Comment: @mkobit: I found a workaround by using the [Node and Label Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter), but it is quite ugly and the plugin is not in development anymore. Furthermore, I created an feature request by Jenkins and I hope that they will implement something (soon or later)..

Comment: Can you reply and show as what you have done ? (even with the ugly way) @Niko

Comment: @codeGeass: I found an alternative way to solve it. I installed the [job-restrictions-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-restrictions). This plugin allows to set restrictions on the node level e.g. I allowed the execution of jobs from the class **org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob** . With this restriction jobs are still starting on the master node but only for the initialization. The execution of the job has to be on another node. The second way is to install the [Node and Label Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter) and to add node label as job parameter.

Comment: @Niko Goold thank you Niko, but may be if you are interested, I had access with the shared library with : "${env.JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/mySharedLib" the JENKINS_HOME will return path before workspace on the master, you can take what you want and run it on slave.